# explicitly solving ODEs using RK4

Tags: python, differential-equations, runge-kutta

My two first order differentials are as follows

```
y1' = -sin(y0) + (gamma)*cos(y0)sin(beta * x)
```

and

```
y0' = y1
```

where

```
(theta)'' = y, (theta)' = y1, theta = y0
```

My original equation was

```
(((d^2)*theta)/dt^2)=-sin(theta)+(gamma)cos(theta)sin(Bx)
```

How do I solve for theta as a function of time and plot from t=0 to t=40. The system starts at rest with `theta = 0 and d(theta)/dt = 0`.

Comment: This is confusing to read.  Looks like you're solving a 2nd order ODE here using 4th order RK4.   True?  Can you edit the original ODE into the question?

Comment: Yeah sure I will put it in now

Comment: Still not clear.  I expect to see one independent variable (time = t) and one dependent variable (theta).  All others should be constants.  What are those arguments for sine?  What's that x?   Are those really sine and cosine with theta as arguments?  (If yes, this is a non-linear ODE.)

Comment: the question is labeled as python yet the code segments are clearly not python.

Comment: got edited into code to highlight the equations but the solution need to be done in python

Comment: and yes the arguments are all as shown above

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are to simulate a **forced physical pendulum** with an oscillating external force.

```
theta''+sin(theta) = gamma * cos(theta)*sin(beta*t)
```

As you have correctly recognized, this needs to be translated into a system of order 1, and then packaged as a vector valued ODE func

```
def odefunc(t,y):
    y0, y1 = y
    return y1, -sin(y0)+gamma*cos(y0)*sin(beta*t)
```

if the constants are global variables, or as parameters

```
def odefunc(t,y,params):
    y0, y1 = y
    beta, gamma = params
    return y1, -sin(y0)+gamma*cos(y0)*sin(beta*t)
```

where you then have to employ lambda expressions to reduce the arguments to the standard format of the ODE integrator.